# Restrict types in Sigma

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, singleton-type

I have type `X` indexed by kind `S` with several functions that work on `X`. For example, `f` converts `X S1` to `X S2` (it doesn't use `X S1` in this simplified example, though).

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, TemplateHaskell, TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Singletons
import Data.Singletons.Sigma
import Data.Singletons.TH

singletons [d|
    data S = S1 | S2 | S3 | S4
  |]

data X (s :: S) = X

f :: X S1 -> X S2
f x = X
```

Now I'd like to define functions that may return `X S2` or `X S3` depending on its argument. The straightforward way would be using `Either`.

```
g1 :: Bool -> X S1 -> Either (X S2) (X S3)
g1 True x = Left X
g1 False x = Right X
```

But I don't want to take this approach because I need to have nested `Either`s when a function returns more types.

Another approach would be using `Sigma` like this.

```
g2 :: Bool -> X S1 -> Sigma S (TyCon X)
g2 True x = SS2 :&: X
g2 False x = SS3 :&: X
```

But this doesn't express the idea that `g2` returns only `X S2` or `X S3`. I can express this idea by introducing a wrapper around `X`.

```
data Y (s :: S) where
    Y2 :: X S2 -> Y S2
    Y3 :: X S3 -> Y S3

singletons [d|
    type Z s = Y s
  |]

g3 :: Bool -> X S1 -> Sigma S ZSym0
g3 True x = SS2 :&: Y2 X
g3 False x = SS3 :&: Y3 X
```

But it's cumbersome to define these wrappers for each combination and unwrap them on caller sites. It'd be nice if I can directly restrict types using `g2` approach, for example, by like applying type constraints, but I'm not sure how I can do it.

How can I directly restrict types using `g2` approach?

I'm using GHC 8.8.4 with [singletons-2.6](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.6).

Comment: What about using a list of types, `g :: Bool -> X S1 -> OneOf '[X S2, X S3]`, for a suitable definition of `OneOf` ?

Comment: @luqui Thank you. I'll try writing it, but I'd appreciate if you gave me some references to such implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question looks too simplified and contrived; it would be nice to have some more concrete motivation. But here is a shot in the dark.

We can define a variant of `Sigma` with a predicate on the first component:

```hs
data SigmaP (i :: Type) (p :: i ~> Constraint) (f :: i -> Type) where
  (:&?:) :: (p @@ x) => Sing x -> f x -> SigmaP i p f
```

Some code to define the predicate seems unavoidable:

```hs
data Y23 :: S ~> Constraint
type instance Apply Y23 x = Y23_ x

type family Y23_ (x :: S) :: Constraint where
  Y23_ S2 = (() :: Constraint)
  Y23_ S3 = (() :: Constraint)
  Y23_ _ = ('True ~ 'False)
```

But now we can just use `X`:

```hs
g3 :: Bool -> X S1 -> SigmaP S Y23 X
g3 True x = SS2 :&?: X
g3 False x = SS3 :&?: X
```

Comment: Thank you. This is something I had in my mind but I didn't know how to write it. Even though I still need to write `Y23` and `Y23_` for each combination, I prefer this to my `g3`.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach inspired by [@luqui's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64148515/restrict-types-in-sigma#comment113436777_64148515). It's similar to [@li-yao-xia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64148979/1378868), but uses an explicit list of types.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, EmptyCase, InstanceSigs, PolyKinds, ScopedTypeVariables, TemplateHaskell, TypeApplications, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators, UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Kind
import Data.Singletons
import Data.Singletons.Prelude
import Data.Singletons.TH

singletons [d|
    data S = S1 | S2 | S3 | S4 deriving (Show, Eq)
  |]

data X (s :: S) = X

data SigmaL (l :: [s :: Type]) (t :: s ~> Type) where
    (:&!:) :: OneOf fst l => Sing (fst :: s) -> t @@ fst -> SigmaL l t

type family OneOf s l :: Constraint where
    OneOf s l = If (Elem s l) (() :: Constraint) ('True ~ 'False)

g5 :: Bool -> X S1 -> SigmaL '[S2, S3] (TyCon X)
g5 True x = SS2 :&!: X
g5 False x = SS3 :&!: X
```